# slidingtab view pager not coming to full screen inside CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, xml, material-design

I need to implement a CollapsingToolbarLayout containing a Relative layout and a tab with viewpager below that. I have achieved ,but View pager is not coming to full screen. This is my code.

`

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/htab_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/htab_collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/White">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/htab_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:titleMarginTop="2dp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <com.wodrob.tatco.wodrobcanvas.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="@color/tabs_background"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`
I tried to give view pager layout outside the Appbar layout, but at that time it is overlapping the CollapsingToolbarLayout and comming to full screen in background.Is there any other way for achieving this??